# PHP regex for admin, admin/ and admin/more/ etc

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently building a CMS for my projects and I'm trying to route to my 'Admin' controller. Now my regexp is:

```
'admin(.*)'
```

But with this everything that start with 'admin' will be matched. I would like to match the route when 'admin', 'admin/foo' and 'admin/foo/bar' etc, is present. Not when 'adminn' or something like that.

Hope you understand what I'm after. Thx / Tobias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alter the regex like this:

```
admin(\/.*)?
```

Answer (score 0):

For string, such as `admin/foo/bar/salami/pizza`, how about `preg_match('~^admin\/~', $string)`?

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches could work without regular expressions at all

- Search for the longest substring first, that way you won't match admin first.  So, with your examples, check for admin/foo/bar first, then admin/foo, then admin.
- explode() the string on the slash, then work your way down the bits to figure out what matches, e.g. explode('/', $request) then check the parts; if the first result is admin, pass it to the admin controller, which can figure out the route from the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
$sample_string="admin/foo/bar";

if(in_array("admin", explode("/",$sample_string))){
 //true
}else{
 //false
}
```

Or you could even replace the explode "/" with explode by "admin".....

Comment: This will match `something/admin/other` and I don't think he wants that.